# Search 1 string on 2 file by steps

Tags: regex, visual-c++, batch-file, vbscript, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to make this script and it has been total failure.

I want to gather a string from an input box, search for that string in a text file 1. If it exists in text file 1, then take the result and search for it in file 2. The result to be show on msgbox or text file or some where I can copy it.

File name and location can be fixed on specific location no need to input them form input box.

OK, I will make another example to clear it more.

Log1.txt

```
\\10.128.214.01      RU00001      Windows 2002 Serv     0 00:02:54

\\10.128.214.02      RU00002      Windows 2002 Serv     0 00:02:54

\\10.128.214.03      RU00003      Windows 2002 Serv     0 00:02:54
```

log2.txt

```
10.128.214.01   RUDH99991   255.255.255.0   10-60-4b-7c-e3-F1   17.07.2013 14:10:21 DHCP
10.128.214.02   RUDH99992   255.255.255.0   10-60-4b-7c-e3-F2   17.07.2013 16:23:40 DHCP
10.128.214.03   RUDH99993   255.255.255.0   10-60-4b-7c-e3-F3   17.07.2013 17:19:30 DHCP
```

If I serach string `RU00001` from inputbox, I want to see the result `RUDH99991` or the full line of it.

Examples are exact similar to actual `log1` and `log2`, so what is shown above is on the `log1` and `log2`.

---

And here is 2 line from the ACTUAL LOG each log contain around 500 line of this format:

Log1.txt

```
\\10.135.0.106          RUX0031              Windows 2002 Serv     1 00:01:44
```

Log2.txt

```
10.135.0.106    RU-NMR-D0125.dc1.dc2.dc3.net    255.255.255.0   00-FF-FF-FF-19-dd   INACTIVE    DHCP
```

Data are changing with scopes etc. It's large file, you got the idea.

Comment: If you find ru1 in log1.txt, how do you know you want dh1 in log2.txt?

Comment: Your Question is quite unclear, when you found your first string, i assume you want to return the int next to it and not the string itself again, right? Use XML for that.

Comment: @Jonest they both have similar string which is 10 or 20 or 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
l1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\log1.txt").ReadAll
l2 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\log2.txt").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.MultiLine = True
're.IgnoreCase = True   'uncomment if you want case-insensitive matches

searchString = InputBox("Enter search string.")

re.Pattern = "\\\\(\S+)\s*" & searchString
For Each m1 In re.Execute(l1)
  re.Pattern = "^" & m1.SubMatches(0) & "\s*(\S+)"
  For Each m2 In re.Execute(l2)
    WScript.Echo m2.SubMatches(0)
  Next
Next
```

Run the script with `cscript.exe` and you can copy the output from the command prompt.

---

If your input files are very large (more than, say, 1 GB in size), reading the entire content of the files may lead to bad performance due to memory exhaustion. In that case it'd be better to process the files line-by-line:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
're.IgnoreCase = True   'uncomment if you want case-insensitive matches

searchString = InputBox("Enter search string.")

re.Pattern = "\\\\(\S+)\s*" & searchString
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\log1.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  For Each m In re.Execute(f.ReadLine)
    match = m.SubMatches(0)
    Exit Do
  Next
Loop
f.Close

If IsEmpty(match) Then WScript.Quit  'no match found

re.Pattern = "^" & match & "\s*(\S+)"
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\log2.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  For Each m In re.Execute(f.ReadLine)
    WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
    Exit Do
  Next
Loop
f.Close
```

which could be simplified by encapsulating the file-processing in a function:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function FindMatch(filename, pattern)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = pattern
  're.IgnoreCase = True   'uncomment if you want case-insensitive matches

  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
  Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    For Each m In re.Execute(f.ReadLine)
      FindMatch = m.SubMatches(0)
      Exit Do
    Next
  Loop
  f.Close
End Function

searchString = InputBox("Enter search string.")

match1 = FindMatch("C:\path\to\log1.txt", "\\\\(\S+)\s*" & searchString)

If IsEmpty(match1) Then WScript.Quit  'no match found

match2 = FindMatch("C:\path\to\log2.txt", "^" & match1 & "\s*(\S+)")

If Not IsEmpty(match2) Then WScript.Echo match2
```

For files with a mere 500 lines I'd stick to the first version, though, because the code is much simpler.

---

BTW, if you want to copy the found match to the clipboard anyway, you can do that directly from the script like this:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate("about:blank")
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
ie.document.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", m.SubMatches(0)
ie.Quit
```

You need to add `about:blank` to the Local Intranet zone for this to work, though (the security setting `Allow Programmatic clipboard access` must be enabled).

Comment: no result at all mate :(

Comment: Well, that's kinda unsurprising when your actual files look entirely different from the sample data you provided before. Answer updated according to modified requirements.

Comment: I had the same grief with changing requirements :/

Comment: +1, But I think it would be better to read and process one line at a time, just in case the log files are very large.

Comment: nothing apper still,and no result :(

Comment: logs are not very large but around 500 lines each

Comment: Worked perfectly fine when I tested it with sample input from your 2nd and 3rd update. You *did* modify the paths to the log files to match your actual paths, didn't you?

Comment: ye mate other wise it wont work,btw iam using win7 if this has to do with anything

Comment: just tested it,and all what i see is black screen in CMD window,NO INFO AT ALL,iam in win 7 mate again

Comment: I tested my code on Win7 before posting. If your paths are correct and you still don't get any output at all, your files are most likely in Unicode format. In that case you need to replace `OpenTextFile("...")` with `OpenTextFile("...", 1, False, True)`.

Answer (score 2):

Check it out:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
SET /p "search=Enter search string (ru1, ru2, ru3): "
SET "chain="
SET "found="
FOR /f "delims=() " %%a IN ('^<log1.txt find "%search%"') DO SET "chain=%%a"
IF NOT DEFINED chain ECHO NOT found: %search% & GOTO :EOF
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=() " %%a IN ('^<log2.txt find "%chain%"') DO SET "found=%%a"
IF NOT DEFINED found ECHO NOT found: %chain% & GOTO :EOF
ECHO FOUND %found%
```

Comment: mate you got close for it

Comment: 2 things mate and you can make it work: first

Comment: ex (  \\10.128.214.01 RU00001 Windows 2002 Serv 000:02:54 )     becouse of the \\ at log1.txt it cant find match so it has to find it with \\

Comment: second :  ex log2.txt ( 10.128.214.01 RUDH99991 255.255.255.0 10-60-4b-7c-e3-F1 17.07.2013 14:10:21 DHCP  )  if i removed the \\ from log1.txt it will find match but will show me this ( 14:10:21 DHCP ) as result,so at least it need to show the full line

Comment: thanks alot for who helped i find it working i just added the string on the code of C+ and it made it alot easy to work

Answer (score 1):

This script both displays the value to the console window and copies the value to the clipboard. If the value is not found, then nothing is displayed and the clipboard is cleared.

```
@echo off
set /p  "search=Enter a search term: "

REM Clear the clipboard
(call )|clip

for /f "delims=\ " %%A in (
  'findstr /rc:"^[^ ]* *%search% " log1.txt'
) do for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%B in (
  'findstr /rc:"^%%A " log2.txt'
) do (

  REM display the value to the screen
  echo %%B

  REM copy the value (without new line) to the clip board
  <nul set /p "=%%B"|clip
)
```

If the format of either file changes, then it should be obvious that the FINDSTR search string as well as the FOR /F options may have to change.

Comment: didnt work for me bro

Comment: @user2566032, My original answer "didn't work" because it was written based on your original poor specification that did not match your actual requirement. Continue to improperly specify what you want, and you can expect answers that "don't work". My answer has been edited to match your newly specified requirements and I verified it works with your sample data.

Comment: mate i try it,even with the exm data and didnt show result and clip is clear